# My frontend prints out both "Category successfully added" and "Category successfully deleted" when I press either add or delete button

Tags: php, html

```
<main>
        <section class="category__title-container">
            <h1 class="category__title">
                Add Category
            </h1>
        </section>
        <section class="error">
        <?php
            if(isset($_GET['error']))
            {
                echo '<font color="red">'.$_GET['error'].'</font>';
                echo '<br><br>';
            }
                                
            if(isset($_GET['ok']))
            {
                echo '<font color="blue">Category successfully added!</font>';
                echo '<br><br>';
            }
                            
        ?>
        </section>
        <section class="add_information-section">
            <form action="addcategory_steps.php" method="post">
                <div class="add_information grid">
                    <div class="add_information-box">
                        <h1 class="add_information-title">
                             Category Name
                        </h1>
                        <input type="text" name="category_name" id="" placeholder="category_name">
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="add_information-box">
                        <h1 class="add_information-title">
                             Category Image
                        </h1>
                        <input type="text" name="category_image" id="" placeholder="category_image">
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Add Category" class="button">
            </form>
        </section>

        <main>
        <section class="category__title-container">
            <h1 class="category__title">
                Delete Category
            </h1>
        </section>
        <section class="error">
        <?php
            if(isset($_GET['error']))
            {
                echo '<font color="red">'.$_GET['error'].'</font>';
                echo '<br><br>';
            }
                                
            if(isset($_GET['ok']))
            {
                echo '<font color="blue">Category successfully deleted!</font>';
                echo '<br><br>';
            }
                            
        ?>
        </section>
        <section class="add_information-section">
            <form action="deletecategory_steps.php" method="post">
                <div class="add_information grid">
                    <div class="add_information-box">
                        <h1 class="add_information-title">
                             Category Name
                        </h1>
                        <input type="text" name="category_name" id="" placeholder="category_name">
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="add_information-box">
                        <h1 class="add_information-title">
                             Category Image
                        </h1>
                        <input type="text" name="category_image" id="" placeholder="category_image">
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Delete Category" class="button">
            </form>
        </section>
```

Above is my code for my php project, but the frontend prints out both successfully deleted and added. How do I make it only to print successfully added if I press the "Add Category" button and only prints out successfully deleted if I press the "Delete Category" button? I have inserted the screenshot of the problem below.

[image: Error in frontend]

Comment: Unrelated fyi: `<font>` is deprecated

Comment: Your `addcategory` and `deletecategory` are both using `$_GET['error']` and `$_GET['ok']` to display their state. Use different naming, like `$_GET['errorAdd']` and `$_GET['errorDelete']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many things wrong that the comment is inadequate

1. Your forms doing a post, so you have to use the $_POST not $_GET
2. You are not setting $_GET['error']
3. You need to use the name attribute for the input/button

`<input type="submit" value="Add Category" class="button" name="addcat">`

`<input type="submit" value="Delete Category" class="button" name="delcat">`

4. Then check which button has been pressed and execute the appropriate code.

`if isset($_POST['addcat'])`  or `if isset($_POST['delcat'])`

5. Depending on the code not posted, you may need separate **error** variables such as `$erroradd` and `$errordel`.